# How to restrict routes in another layout react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having three layouts and they are `Admin`, `App`, `CompanySetup`. I need to restrict routes of app layout in admin layout and vice-versa. I shared my Code below.

Routes.js

```
<Route path='/'>
  <Route path='app'>
    <Route index element={<Home />}></Route>
    <Route
      path='search/category/:category'
      element={<SearchPage />}
    ></Route>
    <Route
      path='search/category/:category/name/:name'
      element={<SearchPage />}
    ></Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path='admin'>
    <Route element={<AdminRouteProvider></AdminRouteProvider>}>
      <Route
        path='dashboard'
        element={<AdminDashboard />}
      ></Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

AppLayout.js

```
<Layout className='min-vh-100 bg-white'>
  <Content className='p-4'>
    <Outlet />
  </Content>
</Layout>
```

AdminLayout.js

```
<Layout className='min-vh-100 bg-white'>
  <Sider width={240} className='bg-white border-end'>
    <Sidebar />
  </Sider>
  <Layout>
    <Header className='bg-body border-bottom'>
      <HeaderNav></HeaderNav>
    </Header>
    <Content className='p-5 bg-body'>
      <AdminRouteProvider>
        <Outlet></Outlet>
      </AdminRouteProvider>
    </Content>
  </Layout>
</Layout>
```

Here I am having separate layouts for `'/app'` and `'/admin'`. My issue is in admin layout `'/app'` is allowed. How to restrict that?

Comment: Can you please clarify how exactly a `"/app"` route` is allowed in the `"/admin"` route space? Where exactly are you layout routes being rendered? Please [edit] to make your issue more clear to readers. Please include a more complete and accurate [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use useEffect/useEffectLayout to prevent from access the route or path of '/app'.

for example-

```
useEffect(()=>{
if(!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('admin')){
window.location.href="/app"
}
},[])
```

this is just an example may this code also change according to your need. If you still facing issue just lemme know.

Comment: I did like that. But here the issue is , Inside AdminRouteProvider , /app route component's child routes displayed. But I need to avoid that and show some message like page you have visited not exist.i.e Admin layout should not allow '/app' or 'search/category/:category' or  'search/category/:category/name/:name'

Comment: okay, then on admin layout you can pass condition like-

{
!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('admin') ? 
<Route path="navigate" element={<Navigation}/>
:
null
}

If you still facing issue just lemme know

Comment: ,Thanks for taking time for me . I slightly changed your suggestion. In app Route I changed like this.  <Route
          path='app'
          element={
            !user.isAdmin ? (
              <Outlet />
            ) : (
              <Result
                status='404'
                title='404'
                subTitle='Sorry, the page you visited does not exist.'             
              />
            )
          }
        >{routes}</Routes>. It works now. Thank you Varun.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are not rendering any actual layout routes for either `"/app"` or `"/admin"`. Import `AppLayout` and `AdminLayout1` and render the appropriate layout routes.

```
import AppLayout from '../path/to/AppLayout';
import AdminLayout from '../path/to/AdminLayout';

...

<Route path="/">
  <Route path="app" element={<AppLayout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="search/category/:category">
      <Route index element={<SearchPage />} />
      <Route path="name/:name" element={<SearchPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="admin" element={<AdminLayout />}>
    <Route path="dashboard" element={<AdminDashboard />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="dashboard" replace />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```